# 'Less compiler error: .input-lg is undefined' after installing Bootstrap in Meteor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I tried 2 packages: `nemo64:bootstrap` and `twbs:bootstrap`

Same error:

While building the application:

> client/lib/custom.bootstrap.less:1121:3: Less compiler error:
>   .input-lg is undefined

After installing the package, I just added a `class="btn btn-info"`. Is it because I need to do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `custom.bootstrap.import.less` file may be corrupted.  You can delete it, and a new one will be generated when the server restarts.